# How to create a live streaming video given pictures in matlab

Tags: matlab, video-streaming

So I have a process that captures images from my webcam, a frame at a time. My process does some adjustment to the image and I want to stream these continuous adjustments. I know I can create an avi file out of these sequences of images, but how do I stream them live?

Comment: when you say stream you mean present on screen or send over the network?

Comment: @cyborg present on the screen, imagine it as a live video feed filter

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this myself, so not sure how well it will work, but [this](http://www.mathworks.com/products/imaq/demos.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/imaq/demoimaq_LiveHistogram.html) demo shows how to get a live histogram from your video stream. I guess it could be modified to do what you want.

> The techniques here can be used to display other live information too. For example, a live video feed can be placed next to a filtered version of the video.